# Line Integral along a Ellipse over a Scalar field

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

> Given is the Line Integral:
>
> $$\int_C = \sqrt{\frac{a^2y^2}{b^2} + \frac{b^2x^2}{a^2}}ds$$
>
> the Path $C$ is along the border of the ellipse with:
>
> $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$$
>
> and moves against Clockwise.

My attampt:
$$\int_C f(x,y) ds = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} f(x(t),y(t)) ||\frac{dr(t)}{dt}|| dt$$

with $$r(t) = (a\cos(t),b\sin(t)) \implies r'(t) = (-a\sin(t), b\cos(t)) \ \ \ \ t\in [0,2\pi]$$

Plugging this in and simplify comes out to:

$$I = \int_{0}^{2\pi} (a^2\sin(t)^2+b^2\cos(t)^2) dt$$

Now i am kinda stuck. I did not use the restricting condition of the ellipse yet. I tried to solve this restriction for either $a$ or $b$ and the plug it in, but this did not really work. Thank you for answering in advance.

Comment: You may refer to older posts of mine [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3702212) and [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2834619).

Comment: For the case of ellipsoids, see also [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2147049) and [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4737663).